# how to select all instances of a model if a string is in input array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

if I got an array like
$tags = ['first', 'second', 'etc']

how do I select all instances of model from database where one of the columns only holds one of values found in the array above.

How would my where look? How do I loop through the array and construc the correct query so I do not miss any objects?

Querently I have decided to place it inside a local scope

```
public function scopeTriptags($query, $triptags) {
    foreach ($triptags as $triptag) {
        $query->orWhere('tripTagPath', $triptag);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I can just chain them using where? if I should use orWhere will that work correctly if orWhere is used in the first loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need of loop and multiple `orWhere()`s here when you can just use [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)  method

```
public function scopeTriptags($query, $triptags) {
    $query->whereIn('tripTagPath', $triptags);
}
```

Comment: yes you are right, I knew about this function but forgot about it